# Casting an Array Literal in C++ to a type (VC++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, g++

Say I have a type edge:

```
struct edge
{
    long long weight;
    int dest;
    inline bool operator<(const edge& other) const
    {
        return weight > other.weight;
    }
};
```

In G++ 4.1.2 (CentOS) I can safely do:

```
edge e = (edge){0, 1};
```

But on MSVC++ 2010, the same code causes:

```
test.cpp(57) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
test.cpp(57) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
test.cpp(57) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
```

Is there a way to do this in MSVC++ compiler?

Comment: Oh ok, I just tried that, and it works. I've been using G++ the whole time, and have been seeing others casting it, so I thought that was the only option. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the cast looked odd to me too.  The syntax (without the cast) goes all the way back to K&R C.

Comment: @Marlon Sorry to bother, but if I have a std::priority_queue of edges, I can't push in an array literal..

Comment: For the pushing, why not make a constructor that takes the two values as arguments, then you can just create a new instance in the push, e.g. `container.push_back(edge(weight, dest));`.

Comment: You keep saying "array literal", but there is no such thing present here -- `edge e = { 0, 1 };` is called _aggregate initialization_ and involves no arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest having a constructor:

```
struct edge  {
   long long weight;
   int dest;
   edge(long long w, int d): weight(w), dest(d) {};
   inline bool operator<(const edge& other) const {
    return weight > other.weight;
   }
};
```

then use

```
edge e (0,1);
```